# Find a power series solution to $y''(x) + (1+x)y'(x) + x^2 y =0$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

> Find a power series solution to $$y''(x) + (1+x)y'(x) + x^2 y =0.$$

I have attached my attempt , but I don't understand how to arrive at the complete solution by simplification each term in terms of 2 arbitrary constants.
Kindly help me out with this .

[image: solution attempt]

[image: solution continued]

Comment: You're almost done, just reindex the last summation too adding two $0$ terms for $n=0,1$ and then equate coefficients corresponding to the same power of $x$ (note that $x$ shoudln't be in this equations).

Comment: @MarcoVergamini I did that , but i am not able to convert every term in terms of only 2 arbitrary constants . Can you please review my solution again ?

Answer (score 1):

Let the solution to the differential equation be $$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
$$\therefore f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1} ;f''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$$
$$\therefore \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+(1+x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}+x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=0$$
$$\therefore \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n+2}=0$$
Reindexing the summations,
$$\therefore \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n+2}=0$$
Equating coefficients, we get
$$2a_2+a_1=0$$
$$6a_3+2a_2+a_1=0 \implies a_3=0$$
$$(n+4)(n+3)a_{n+4}+(n+3)a_{n+3}+(n+2)a_{n+2}+a_n=0$$ $$\therefore n(n-1)a_n+(n-1)a_{n-1}+(n-2)a_{n-2}+a_{n-4}=0$$ 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution but i had also done till this point as shown in my attempt, i am not getting how to arrive at a general solution beyond that point containing only 2 arbitrary constants. Please show me how to compress these terms . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure you will be able to. I used Wolfram Alpha to solve the differential equation and the solution is quite complicated :) Sorry I couldn't be of more help :) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2B%281%2Bx%29y%27%2Bx%5E2y%3D0